# How to override Webkit Apperance for select tag?

Tags: css, webkit-appearance

**User-agent Content:**

```
*
{
 -webkit-appearance: none
}
```

I need to override something like `-webkit-appearance: select`.

Comment: I don't get your point. What is in the **user agent stylesheet** (and on which browser BTW), and what's in **your**  stylesheet ? And what do you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `select` value for -webkit-appearance:

You can use `menulist` for select.

```
-webkit-appearance:menulist;/*it applies to select*/
```

Comment: That's why iasked this question @C-link Nepal. How to do it then? My ultimate aim is displaying the dropdwon arrow.

Comment: I cannot modify the html. That's the problem

Comment: You can use menulist for the select: -webkit-appearance: menulist will do the trick...